# Ipad IOS 7 Safari Iframe freeze only vertically

Tags: ipad, iframe, rotation, ios7, freeze

I was required to display my website in a full page iframe, which was already a pain in the ass (I'm ranting sorry).

In the I have a select input and it seems that after I make a selection the screen freezes when the screen is vertical but if I put it in landscape mode it works like a charm.

Also the same thing happens when I go from landscape to vertical mode and again all comes back to normal back in landscape mode.

I though it could be due to some of my scripts but I remove everything and I still got the issue.

And I forgot to mention it, but there was no issue at all before installing ios 7.

I'm at it for a while so any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: Does not help, but you are not alone: https://discussions.apple.com/message/23244123#23244123

Answer (score 0):

I tried reducing the code to the minimum cleaning out the unecessary stuff and putting everything together in a single file instead of using partial pages. Since then it seems to work so I'm gonna leave like that it's been long enough.

Still not sure what was the issue even though it worked on IOS 6 and  without the iframe or in landscape mode on IOS 7. Anyway I'm done with it